# how to determine battery level of airpods in swift

Tags: swift, batterylevel, batterymanager, airpods

I have been learning about swift for sometimes. I have made an test app that shows user Battery Level and Storage details of the phone. Now i am exploring other possibilities. Is there anyway i can show the Battery Level of AirPods that are connected to the corresponding Device? If anyone has any solution or Guideline, that will be much Appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

How about importing `CoreBluetooth`

then create an instance of `CBCentralManager`.

if `central.state == .poweredOn`

then start scanning for airpods with the specific UUID

`centralManagerInstance.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [airPodsUUID], options: nil)`

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
    if let manufacturerData = advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataManufacturerDataKey] as? Data {
        let batteryLevel = Int(manufacturerData[1])
        print("AirPods battery level: \(batteryLevel)%")
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to hardcode the UUID. you can use the `centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: nil)` method to scan for all bluetooth devices and look for the advertisment data which contains the AirPods manufacturer ID (0x004C):

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
    if let manufacturerData = advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataManufacturerDataKey] as? Data,
        manufacturerData.count >= 1,
        manufacturerData[0] == 0x4C {
        // This is an AirPods device
        let batteryLevel = Int(manufacturerData[1])
        print("AirPods battery level: \(batteryLevel)%")
    }
}
```